# Downloading HLS Livestream for Offline Usage in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, avplayer, http-live-streaming

I am developing an iOS app using SwiftUI, and I want to provide the functionality to download an HLS (HTTP Live Streaming) livestream for offline usage. However, I'm facing difficulties finding specific examples or tutorials on how to achieve this in SwiftUI.

Could anyone provide me with some guidance or point me to resources that demonstrate how to download HLS livestreams for offline playback using SwiftUI? I would appreciate any code snippets, libraries, or step-by-step explanations that can help me implement this feature successfully.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Apples sample online works with SwiftUI too

Comment: @loremipsum Could you please share link

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/offline_playback_and_storage/using_avfoundation_to_play_and_persist_http_live_streams